# Broke his leg VS Broke its leg

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Which one is correct of the following.

1. The Horse fell and broke **its leg.**
2. The Horse fell and broke **his leg.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["it" or "he/she" for animals](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151111/it-or-he-she-for-animals)

Comment: Yes it did but can I hope for a little more explanation? A little and easy?

Comment: If you know the horse by name and think of him/her as an individual, it's _him/her_. If it's an unidentified horse that just happens to have caused a traffic accident, it's _it_.