# who for animals in mind

Tags: grammar

the following sentences are written in my textbook

"this art exhibitoon was curated by Rocky" (Rocky is a dog btw)
"Rocky belongs to art critic Jessica"

and the question they ask was
"Who is responsible for curating the art exhibition?"

I thought it was Jessica because  they were asking "Who" not "What"

but the answer was "Rocky" because "the exhibition was curated by Rocky"

although I think it is a person who can curate an exhibiton not a dog.

My Question:
If the answer to the question is an animal, is it okay to ask with "who"?
and hence, if the question is asked with "who"  do you have to give a person as the anwer?

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151111/it-or-he-she-for-animals

Comment: We certainly use "who" for dogs: eg "Who's a good boy then? You are."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of opinion Some people think of animals (particularly pets) as members of their family and customarily refer to them as though they are people. Others have no such affinity with animals and would never use "who" to refer to one.

The problem here is that we are asked to believe that an animal can take charge of an art exhibition and organise it. In children's storybooks, it is common to have talking animals who could do such a thing. In real life we need much more context to understand what this means.

Without the extra context it is very difficult to make a decision. If, in future a computer were able to curate an exhibition without human intervention then we will have to decide whether to refer to the computer as "who".

In this case, if a dog were to completely organise an exhibition without human intervention, then I personally think it would *deserve* to be referred to with "who"!

Comment: i think the dog was just a symbol, because the exhibition was for dogs not for humans. when i read the text, it was Jessica who sorta did everything. (Rocky wasn't really personified..)... In this case, is it okay to ask the question using "who" or do you have to use "Which" if the answer to the quesiton is Rocky;

Comment: An exhibition for dogs is in itself a way of anthropomorphising them. It is consistent with this to pretend that a dog organised the exhibition. In this case the use of "who" is intended to continue the pretence. In that way it is similar to a children's story. In *Goldilocks and the Three Bears* for example, the bears are presented as people in all but form. They eat at a table, sleep in beds, and so on. It makes sense to children to refer to them as though they were people. In the same way, this article treats dogs as though they are people making the use of "who" appropriate.